# What are the things in the __init__ parentheses called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization

What are the things in the parentheses in the **init** called.

```py
class Mother:

    def __init__ (self, strName = "Maya", strAddress = "717 Lynx Street"):
        self.name = strName
        self.address = strAddress

    def play(self):
        print("Playing games.")

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name + " at " + self.address + " "

class Son(Mother):
    pass

mySon = Son()
mySon.name = "Jeff"
mySon.play()

print(mySon)
```

What is the strName = "Maya" and strAddress = "717 Lynx Street"? What are they called? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are arguments of the method `__init__`. If you specify a value using `=` after the name of the argument, it will be the default value of this argument.

Some examples

```
>>> m1 = Mother("Juliana", "123 Apple Street")
>>> m2 = Mother("Francisca")
>>> m3 = Mother()
>>> m1.strName
'Jualiana'
>>> m1.strAddress
'123 Apple Street'
>>> m2.strName
'Francisca'
>>> m2.strAddress
'717 Lynx Street'
>>> m3.strName
'Maya'
>>> m3.strAddress
'717 Lynx Street'
```

You are applying class inheritance to your class `Son`. This means that it will inherit all the instance variables and methods from your base class `Mother`. Therefore, you are inheriting the `__init__` method which uses those default values.

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments (or just "arguments"), in this case arguments with default values, making them optional arguments.